# Error when adding Datepicker to a remote component in module federation

Tags: angular, angular-material, nrwl-nx, webpack-module-federation

I am trying to use datepicker within an remote component using module federation and am getting the attached error message.
[image]

**Troubleshooting steps tried**

- Added @angular/material as shared library to webpack config of all
  projects
- Tried adding @angular/material/core as shared library to webpack
  config of all projects
- Added MatDatepickerModule and MatNativeDateModule to import of App
  Modules of both base and remote projects
- Tried Adding MatDatepickerModule and MatNativeDateModule as providers
  too.
- Tried installing @angular/material-moment-adapter and using it
  instead of MatNativeDateModule.

**Reproduction**

Steps to reproduce:

- Clone the repo with the sample app containing the error([click this link](https://github.com/srukshan98/nx-ng-mfe-date-picker-issue))
- run npm install
- run following commands in separate terminals
- npx ng s
- npx nx build remote -c=development --watch
- npx http-server dist/apps

**Environment**

Angular: 12.3.3

CDK/Material: 12.2.13

Browser(s): Microsoft Edge

Operating System (e.g. Windows, macOS, Ubuntu): Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to add '@angular/material/datepicker' as a shared package in webpack config.

The second error that I got was saying that mat=form-field did not contain MatFormFieldControl. Which was fixed by importing MatInputModule to both remote module and Shell App Module.

The attached repo now work. anyone can check the changes by looking at the changes done.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates your app is not providing the necessary service `DateAdapter`;

[The angular material's docs](https://v12.material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) state that we need to import `MatNativeDateModule` from the root component; or provide an alternative for it. (have a look on their live examples to see how they recommend you use it)

In your git repo, you are importing it from the component which uses the date picker, and that might be your problem in the actual app.

Your git repo worked fine for me btw, without console errors:

[image]

Comment: what is the node and angular cli version that you are running?

Comment: cli runs with the same as your repo, node v14

Comment: what is the minor and patch version?

Comment: the node version is not relevant for this issue. As I said the app builds, and that's usually where node's interference ends. I suggest you delete your node_modules folder and reinstall the dependencies, as it worked on my environment, from a fresh copy.

Comment: I have tried it, but am still getting the error if mat-form-field is kept, if I comment out the mat-form-field then it works including the date picker. but that is not what i want

Answer (score 1):

I've added the modules in the web-pack.config.ts of shell and container app. And in module.ts of both shell and container apps. Then it worked for me :)

```
    // '@angular/material/core': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: "12.2.13" },
    // '@angular/cdk': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: "12.2.13" },
    // '@angular/material/datepicker': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: "12.2.13" },
```